# xna draw text to screen when camera following object

Tags: xna

Currently I have the camera following an image, but now decided I want to display some text on the top of the screen.
I have found using the following code it makes the text move around the screen as the location of 20, 20 is changing. (which makes sense as the camera is following an object, position 20, 20 is static).

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "test", new Vector2(20, 20), Color.White);
```

The camera is being updated with the following code.

```
        _viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-this.Position.X, -this.Position.Y, 0)) *
                        Matrix.CreateRotationZ(this.Rotation) *
                        Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) *
                        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewPort.Width * 0.5f, viewPort.Height * 0.5f, 0));
```

Its late, and feel I am missing something obvious, but if I want to always display "Test" of the screen regardless of where the camera is, how do you go about it?

Comment: Are you asking to make the text stay on top of the object (i.e. move on screen) or to make text stay on the same position on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: Start another sprite batch (ie: call `Begin`), without passing a view matrix.

Comment: Absolute legend, I really should have known that! Thank you for your help.